# How Windows automatically detects proxy settings

Tags: windows, networking, proxy

I had a proxy in my network, it is still alive but I don't want to use it anymore.

I removed wpad entry from DNS and I removed DHCP 252 options.

Now my Windows10 workstation with ONLY "Automatically detect network settings" flagged, is still using my proxy.
I confirm that if I remove that flag I don't use the proxy but I dont't know why, but with that flag I still use the proxy.

What are other methods for autoconfiguration?

This is my regedit content for HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings]
"DisableCachingOfSSLPages"=dword:00000000
"IE5_UA_Backup_Flag"="5.0"
"PrivacyAdvanced"=dword:00000001
"SecureProtocols"=dword:00000800
"CertificateRevocation"=dword:00000001
"User Agent"="Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Win32)"
"ZonesSecurityUpgrade"=hex:28,73,63,b5,62,ef,d3,01
"WarnonZoneCrossing"=dword:00000000
"EnableNegotiate"=dword:00000001
"MigrateProxy"=dword:00000001
"ProxyEnable"=dword:00000000
"EnableHttp1_1"=dword:00000001
"ProxyHttp1.1"=dword:00000001
"EnableHTTP2"=dword:00000001
"EnablePunycode"=dword:00000001
"UrlEncoding"=dword:00000000
"DisableIDNPrompt"=dword:00000000
"ShowPunycode"=dword:00000000
"WarnonBadCertRecving"=dword:00000001
"WarnOnPostRedirect"=dword:00000001


[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Cache]
"Persistent"=dword:00000000

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Connections]
"SavedLegacySettings"=hex:46,00,00,00,7a,47,00,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"Connessione LAN"=hex:46,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,01,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
"DefaultConnectionSettings"=hex:46,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,09,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,\
  00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: In Settings > Network & Internet > Proxy, is "Use a proxy server set" to Off? See also under the registry key `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` if you have an item named `ProxySettingsPerUser` and try to toggle its value between 1 and 0, reboot if changed.

Comment: Proxy is off in settings and I don't have this regkey.

Comment: What do you have under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings` ? A screenshot of regedit might help. And what is the output of `netsh.exe winhttp show proxy`?

Comment: I attach my regedit keys  in the answer. Netsh command replies with "direct access".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end it was some cache.

I had to remove this key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Wpad
```

Disable **WinHTTP AutoProxy** service reboot twice.
And now it is working.